# Windows10 jssc.SerialPortException: openPort(); Exception type - Port busy

Tags: java, javafx, serial-port, serial-communication, jssc

I'm new to java but not to programming. I'm trying to understand how to use serial port in java. I'm trying to develop a code that will require to open and close a serial port multiple times during runtime.

On my test code I use checkbox that when checked it will open the serial port and will close if unchecked. Somehow after I close the port for the first time 
and then reopen again for second, third, etc time I get an exemption error.

Here are the console logs

```
Open Port
Close Port
Open Port
jssc.SerialPortException: Port name - COM1; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Port busy.
Close Port
Open Port
jssc.SerialPortException: Port name - COM1; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Port busy.
```

I also found this code and added to the code prior closing but I still can't open the port on the second and succedding tries...

---

```
if (serialPort != null && serialPort.isOpened ()) {
    serialPort.purgePort (1);
    serialPort.purgePort (2);
    serialPort.closePort ();
}
```

---

Hoping to someone can point me to the right direction or correct my code. Thanks you and advance. I'm using Windows 10 64bit  by the way.

Here is my test code...

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import jssc.SerialPort;
import jssc.SerialPortException;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setTitle("Serial Test");

        // CONNECT CheckBox
        CheckBox connectBox = new CheckBox("OPEN PORT");

        connectBox.setOnAction(e -> {
            SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM1");
            if (connectBox.isSelected()) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Open Port");


                    if (serialPort != null && serialPort.isOpened ()) {
                          serialPort.purgePort (1);
                          serialPort.purgePort (2);
                          serialPort.closePort ();
                        }
                    if (serialPort.openPort()) serialPort.closePort();
                    serialPort.openPort();
                    serialPort.setParams( 115200, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
                } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            } else {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Close Port");
                    if (serialPort != null && serialPort.isOpened ()) {
                          serialPort.purgePort (1);
                          serialPort.purgePort (2);
                          serialPort.closePort ();
                        }
                } catch (SerialPortException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }   
            }
        });
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(connectBox);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 400, 200));
        primaryStage.show();    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please be sure not to have any virtual machine open. It usually happens to me :D